# process bz2 file and process using awk

Tags: awk, bzip2, bz2, bzip

I have a file called "text.bz2" which contains a number of records which i want to process. I have a script which successfully processes all the data in a standard text file and outputs the results to a different "results.txt" file, but the command I'm currently running outputs all the results of the bz2 file to the command prompt (like cat does), creates the results.txt file - but it is empty.

This is the cammand I'm running:

```
bzip2 -dc text.bz2 | awk ... '
'
> results.txt
```

The format of the data in the decompressed bz2 file is:

```
field1=xxx;field2=xxx;field3=111222222;field4=xxx;field5=xxx
field1=xxx;field2=xxx;field3=111222222;field4=xxx;field5=xxx
field1=xxx;field2=xxx;field3=111222333;field4=xxx;field5=xxx
field1=xxx;field2=xxx;field3=111222444;field4=xxx;field5=xxx
field1=xxx;field2=xxx;field3=111222555;field4=xxx;field5=xxx
field1=xxx;field2=xxx;field3=111222555;field4=xxx;field5=xxx
field1=xxx;field2=xxx;field3=111222777;field4=xxx;field5=xxx
field1=xxx;field2=xxx;field3=111222888;field4=xxx;field5=xxx
```

and the output is exactly as expected, as below, but instead of the results being output to a text file, it's output to the command window:

```
111222333 111
111222444 111
111222555 111
111222777 222
111222888 111
```

What am i doing wrong with my bzip / redirection command?

Many thanks

Comment: Hi Ed - more info added as requested. The awk process works perfectly - i just need to redirect the output to a text file rather than it appear in the window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the `> file` at the end of the awk command, not on the line after it:

```
foo | awk 'script' > file
```

not

```
foo | awk 'script'
> file
```

Comment: Hi Ed. If i do that i get "awk: cmd. line:4: ^ syntax error"

Comment: Thankyou... sorted!